# Append rows to an existing Excel file, on an Azure File Share, using a free dotnet library, from an Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net-core, export-to-excel

I want to **append** rows to an existing Excel spreadsheet file stored on an Azure File Share.

The spreadsheet contains existing historical data, and charts plotting this data, so I don't want to have to recreate it, simply **add rows to an existing data table**.

I'd like to do this with a free Excel library.

My code is running in an Blob triggered Azure Function, where the blob file is the csv data that I want to append.

Of the libraries I've tried to achive this with so far, [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) doesn't seem to allow you to write to an existing Excel file, only read in its data, and then rewrite a new file (according to [this](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI/issues/33)).

[SpreadCheetah](https://github.com/sveinungf/spreadcheetah) also seems to completely overwrite existing data, rather than appending to it (I tried this [example](https://github.com/sveinungf/spreadcheetah-samples/blob/main/SpreadCheetahSamples/WriteToFile.cs)).

I looked into using an Interop approach, but as I understand it, this wouldn't be possible running in an Azure Function. (It would need to download the file to a local drive first?)

Am I doing something wrong with these libraries? Is there another free Excel library I could use to acheive this? Or do I need to stop being cheap, and pay up for one? (If so, which would be the cheapest one that would allow this functionality?) Or is this a weird edge case situation that noone in their right minds would be doing anyway?!

Thanks for any advice or workarounds anyone can suggest.

Comment: You want to append data to csv file or an excel file?

Comment: Is your file stored in Azure File Share or in Azure Blob Storage?
If you have a scenario where you simply want to append data to a CSV file, you might take a look at [Append Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-append)

Comment: Append csv data I get from the blob trigger, to an existing Excel (.xslx) file

Comment: @FFranz thank you so much, I wasn't aware of them before, and it seems like just appending the csv data coming in to the Az Function to a single Append Blob, and then using this as a data source for a separate Excel file to report on would be a much better approach that fighting to get the data into a single xlsx file.

Comment: @Ted you're welcome, I hope this approach helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already recommended, if you have a append scenario where you just want to append incoming csv data to a single blob, Azure Storage offers [Append Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-append), which are optimized for scenarios like that.

Comment: Danke schon Franz!

Comment: My pleasure! :)